# How to I get a class function to return an integer and not an object?

Tags: php, function, class, oop, while-loop

I want to create a plugin in WordPress, but I beleive that my issue is purely PHP related, so I'm posting here.

Essentially, I want to retrieve a result from a variable that I pass into a function. A super simplified example can be found below:

```
class my_class {
    public function my_function($my_var){
        return $my_var;
    }

}

$my_class = new my_class();
$var = 10;
$my_function_result = $my_class->my_function($var);
$x = 1; 
while($x <= 5) {
    echo $my_function_result . '<br>';
     $x++;
};
```

When I have this as just a plain PHP file (i.e. locahost/test/) things work as expected, however, in WordPress, I'm getting a loop like:

```
int(10) 10
int(10) 10
int(10) 10
int(10) 10
int(10) 10
```

I'm just starting out with OOP, so I've no idea what's going on. Also, please forgive me if I've mis-titled this or am using the wrong nomenclature.

Can anyone point me into the write direction as to why it's outputting the int(#) first?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're just `echo`ing the variable, it wouldn't print `int(10)`, that most likely comes from a `var_dump()`. That being said though, PHP does type-juggling, so if it's a string or int doesn't usually matter, `10 == "10"` is true.

Comment: Yes, the `int(10)` is coming from a `var_dump()`

Comment: Yes, this was a dum dum mistake. I had a large file and overlooked an erroneous/superfluous var_dump.

Regardless, huge thanks, your comments just stopped me form continuing down a useless rabbit hole and I really appreciate it!